# How do I write a good peer review?

Tags: peer-review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scope for the role of peer reviewer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/498/scope-for-the-role-of-peer-reviewer)

For the first time, I have been asked to do a peer review. I have accepted, because the paper is well within my expertise, and I don't have less time than others.

Are there any established guidelines, checklists, etc. on *how to actually do a good peer review*? One might consider it common sense (*just read the article critically and raise any issues*), but I think it might still be helpful to have some checklist on things to look for. For example, is it my responsibility to check that the references are correct? Should I mention cosmetics ("figure X hard to read"), or focus only on the content? And if I do focus on the content, are there specific strategies in doing so?

The manuscript (draft) is a full length journal article.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this is a duplicate of http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/498/1033 but I'm not sure